# Using collection of Enum that implement an interface

Tags: java, enums

I have an *interface*

```
public interface State {
    String name();
}
```

A function that wants a collection of said States

```
void processStates(Collection<State> states){
//...
}
```

and an enum that implements this

```
public enum StatesEnum implements State {
    DUMMYSTATE1
}
```

When I try to call the function like so

```
List<StatesEnum> listOfStates = new ArrayList<>();
listOfStates.add(DUMMYSTATE1);
processStates(listOfStates)
```

This gives an `Error:(29, 78) java: incompatible types: java.util.List<StatesEnum> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<State>`

What have I understood wrong about enums?

Comment: "What have I understood wrong about enums?" actually you've misunderstood generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.util.List<StatesEnum> cannot be converted to java.util.Collection<State>` this says it all , you can't assign `List<StatesEnum>` type to `Collection<State>`.

change `(Collection<State> states)` to `(Collection<? extends State> states` ,but remember you won't be able to add anything other than `null` to `states` after this.

Comment: Alternatively, change `listOfStates` to be a `List<State>`.